# My ScrollView is scrolling even when my contentsize is smaller than its frame

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I created this tree in an `IB`:

- `UIViewController`

  - `UIView`
  - `UIScrollView` (x=50 y=50 width=468 height=270) (background a visible color to differentiate)

In my controller I explicit do `theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(X,X)`.

When I run the program I still have vertical scrolls even when my contentsize height is smaller than the frame height. Using height values greater than 253 (254 258 ..) but still smaller than 270 make the scrolls appear. Using < 253 the completely disappear.

The horizontal axis has a weird behavior also. The only way to make the horizontal scrolls appear is by setting the content > 471. It means that with 469 and 470 scrolls are still hidden.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that autolayout is disabled in your storyboard. This is to make sure that the content size isn't being reset after the line of code you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard maybe I had to say that I'm using a uinavigationcontroller to hold my uiviewcontroller.

Comment: I can assure u that the line of code I mentioned is the last that the code executes. I did that because if I disable my auyolayout all my view goes to hell

Comment: It's not exactly a matter of the last line of code being executed, auto layout can mess things up in a way that it re-assignes the frame to the UIScrollView as a result of other things going on. Try logging the UIScrollView's frame and content size and see that you're getting unexpected values

Comment: After I set my content size, I immediately print:
CONTENTSIZE : 453 , 270
FRAME : 50 50 468 270
BOUNDS : 0 0 468 270
and still having my vertical scrolls

Comment: Try printing as you scroll (within scrollViewDidScroll)

Comment: You are right. My Prints: 
* FIRST CONTENTSIZE: 468 253 
*FIRST FRAME: 468 270 //FIRST MEANS (LAST LINE OF CODE PRINTING) 
//AFTER SCROLLING FRAME: 468 250.... 
There is something that is changing my scrollview height. I don't know if this matters -> my view is in landscape mode and I have to rotate it to test it. Maybe I have to override a method to avoid some kind of resize because of the autolayout

Comment: I think that your best chance would be to figure out the constraints that are causing this and add another constraint that can co-exist with the other constraints, one that would make sure that the height stays as you would expect. Another option would be to turn off autolayout and start from scratch. I personally advise you to do the latter.

Comment: I got a solution.

My main problem is that i had to override wantsfullscreenlayout in my controller, because my status bar was conditioning all my subviews including the scroll view. For more info, check this : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH13-SW2